# what proportion of positive integers have exactly N pairs of consecutive integer factors?

Tags: number-theory

This is a followon to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038712/what-proportion-of-positive-integers-have-two-factors-that-differ-by-1), which asked for the proportion of integers that have (any) consecutive integer factors.

Now, what proportion has **exactly** one pair?  Since every odd number is = (2*n+1), we have to reject any integer K with factors 2, n, (2n+1).    It looks as though there will be some ugly formula that starts with {2,n} and disallows (2n+1) ... **and** , when 2^j is a factor of n, disallows 2^(j+1) as a factor of K.

So, as a followon, I'll leave the general case as well:  what proportion of positive integers has exactly  N pairs of consecutive factors?

Comment: Clearly deserves a vote.